# Django querying against external database with different timezone

Tags: mysql, django, database, postgresql

I have a Django API application running on postgres with `TIME_ZONE='America/New_York'` and `USE_TZ = True`.

For a daily report, I need to query another database, MySQL, and compare records from the postgres DB to check for some updates. They should contain the same number of results. The MySQL DB's timezone is `UTC` however. How can I perform `SELECT` queries against the MySQL DB to have it match the same date range on my postgres DB?

Example:
These two queries should return the same number of results

```
# Django/Postgres with TIME_ZONE='America/New_York'`
MyObject.objects.filter(created_on__date=date(2016, 9, 17))

# External MySQL Databse in UTC
sql.execute('SELECT * from MY_TABLE where created_on BETWEEN "2016-09-17" AND "2016-09-18"')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is to convert the date in MySQL to match `America/New_York` time zone.

The function to achieve that would be [`CONVERT_TZ()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz) and since you need named time zone first you need to set up [time zone tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time-zone-support.html).

If you are uncertain whether named time zones are available issue below query - if it returns zero the table is empty so using named time zones is unavailable and you need to populate them (I've mentioned a link to documentation above).

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mysql.time_zone_name;
```

[`mysql_tzinfo_to_sql`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-tzinfo-to-sql.html) is used to populate time zones tables.

If your time zone is not a moving one then you can go with less safe, hardcored approach (not recommended) by explicitly typing the time difference like so:

```
mysql> SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2016-09-17 10:00:00','+00:00','+06:00');
        -> '2016-09-17 16:00:00' -- Result
```